# stream a big dataset from server and visualize the data asynchronously

Tags: node.js, d3.js, dc.js, data-stream

Is there a way to stream a big dataset from server and visualize the data with dc.js in an async fashion?

Chunk the dataset then update the visualization on the client with the chunks as they arrive.

Like this page: http://vcf.iobio.io/?vcf=http://s3.amazonaws.com/vcf.files/ExAC.r0.2.sites.vep.vcf.gz&species=Human&build=GRCh37

Comment: I'm sure there's a way.

Comment: @Eric, How do I go about do that?

Comment: @EricGuan, I love that answer. I always want to say that. The answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is set up all your charts and then set a recurrent interval timer that fetches chunks and calls [crossfilter.add](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_add) and then [dc.redrawAll()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.html#.redrawAll__anchor):

```
var cf = crossfilter([]); // start with no data
// set up dimensions, groups, and charts, then ...
window.setInterval(function() {
    d3.csv(/* your data source with chunk parameters */, function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            // preprocess data
        });
        cf.add(data);
        dc.redrawAll();
    });
}, 5000); // or choose an appropriate interval for processing your chunks
```

There may be a more intelligent way to chain the requests so that there is always an ajax request in flight, and a chunk of data being processed by the browser. (Probably starting the next request as soon as the last one has arrived.)

But I think this is the best way to get started because it is easy to understand.

I don't know of a public data source with a restful chunk API, but if you know of one and can create a fiddle example, I'm sure an example would help a lot of people.

Comment: Can I set up a file stream from the server using node data stream function as a data source?

Comment: Again, I'm sure the answer is yes. But I don't know node, so I can't help much. I imagine a restful API on the server that takes an offset and chunk length, and the client would keep track of how much it has already read.